# Using Jade instead of HB in ultimate-seed

Tags: express, handlebars.js, pug

I love ultimate-seed (https://github.com/pilwon/ultimate-seed), but I want to use Jade instead of HB for server-side templating on express. Is that possible? What should I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, express comes built in with jade so I'm sure you can just use that instead.

Comment: Will you please elaborate on how to use Jade instead? Are any code changes necessary?

Comment: Yeah you have to use thie `app.set('view engine', 'jade');` Check here https://stormpath.com/blog/build-nodejs-express-stormpath-app/